# MVC3 ASPX ViewBag / Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view that is using a model

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Program.Models.Test>"
```

I am displaying data in the view using:

```
> <%= this.Model.Item == null ? "" :
> Html.GetString(this.Model.Item.Name) %>
```

Now I am trying to display a different item from another model on the same view, I thought ViewBag might help, so in my controler, I added:

```
ViewBag.GuideLines = ctx.GuideLines;
```

My question is can I display a specific item value from Guidelines model on the same view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought ViewBag might help

Wrong thought. ViewBag/ViewData never helps. I never use those 2 in any ASP.NET MVC application.

> Now I am trying to display a different item from another model on the same view

Simply add this other model as property of the main view model. So you will have `Model.Guidelines` in the view.

Comment: Thanks, I added     public GuideLineRepository glr = new GuideLineRepository(); to the Model.

Answer (score 0):

in general if you need to use one or more of your domain models for use in a single page, you would create a viewmodel, basically a POCO that would contain just the properties from your domain objects (or any other information) that your view would need to be aware of.  you would then strongly ype your view to this new viewmodel type and access the properties as per normal.