# Selected SelectListItem to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have a List to pass to my view in ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult ContactUs()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> reasons = new List<SelectListItem>();
        reasons.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = true,
            Text = "Billing/Payment question",
            Value = "Billing/Payment question"
        });
        reasons.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Complaint",
            Value = "Complaint"
        });

        ViewBag.reasons = reasons;
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactUs(ContactUs form)
{
    //some code
    return View("ContactUs");
}
```

Model:

```
[Required]
public String Reason { get; set; }
```

Veiw:

```
@model #####.ViewModels.ContactUs
@using (Html.BeginForm("ContactUs","Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Reason,  (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.reasons);
}
```

I need to create a dropdownlist , perhaps DropDownList("reasons") (should be better way of writing this) form the ViewBag.reasons and pass the **selected** value to my Model, as property String Reason. Just confused about usage of the DropDownList/DropDownListFor.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    public String Reason { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var reasons = new List<SelectListItem>();
    reasons.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Selected = true,
        Text = "Billing",
        Value = "Billing"
    });
    reasons.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Complaint",
        Value = "Complaint"
    });
    ViewBag.reasons = reasons;
    return View(new MyModel());
}
```

View:

```
@model MyModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Reason, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.reasons,
    "-- select a reason --"  
)
```

---

but I would recommend you to get rid of ViewBag and use real view models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Reason { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Reasons { get; set; }
}
```

and then the controller action will populate the view model and pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var reasons = new List<SelectListItem>();
    reasons.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Billing",
        Value = "Billing"
    });
    reasons.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Complaint",
        Value = "Complaint"
    });

    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        // Notice how I am using the Reason property of the view model
        // to automatically preselect a given element in the list
        // instead of using the Selected property when building the list
        Reason = "Billing",
        Reasons = reasons
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in your strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Reason,
    Model.Reasons,
    "-- select a reason --"  
)
```

Comment: I know what you mean, but for this scenario, just need to pass the list in ViewBag. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Chuchelo, well, I am just obligated to point out good practices. You could ignore them and continue using ViewBag of course.

Comment: I get error same as before :"There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Reason'." Any idea why ? The code is compiled.

Comment: How does your DropDownList call look like in the view? Are you using `DropDownList` or `DropDownListFor`?

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Reason, (IEnumerable < SelectListItem >) ViewBag.reasons);

Comment: Are you passing a model to your view when returning it : `return View(someModel);`? Could you show your full controller action code? Mine works. I have tested it. So there must be something else in your code.

Comment: @Chuchelo, when are you getting the exception? When showing the Index page or when submitting the form? Because in your POST action I don't see you populating `ViewBag.reasons` anywhere and yet you render the same view. If you don't set the `ViewBag.reasons` in your POST action it won't work. Where do you think the values of the dropdown will come from? If you intend to redisplay the same view make sure that `ViewBag.reasons` is assigned a list of options, the same way you did in your GET action. HTTP is a stateless protocol and there's no ViewState in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: get exception when submitting a form. I populated the ViewBag in regular action(not post), then from View the chosen item's value (as string) needs to get into the Model in the Post action.

Comment: @Chuchelo, as I said, make sure you populate ViewBag.reasons in your POST action.

Comment: how do I preserve the Model.Reasons so that it gets to the post Action ? By using a hidden field in the view ?

Comment: Darin, why is it a best practice to have such things in Model rather than in ViewBag?
[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155455/mvc3-aspx-viewbag-model) you strongly recommend against ViewBags as well. Why?

Comment: There are lots of reasons why ViewBag is bad. `ViewBag` is weakly typed. You have no compile time safety. You have no Intellisense. It's just horrible to use ViewBag/ViewData. But the worst thing about ViewBag is that it is a reflection to a very bad practice in ASP.NET MVC: using your domain models in the views instead of defining view models. You should never be passing domain models to views. Controller action must always take and pass only view models from and to views. View models is a sort of projection of your domain for a given view.

Comment: @Darin: This is getting off topic, but this has been bothering me for quite some time and I see different answers all the time. Could you please tell me if it would be a good practice to have multiple domain objects in my view-model? Example: **CreateCustomerModel** (view-model) would have **Customer** and **Car** domain objects. I appreciate your advice.

Comment: @Dmitry, this is acceptable if  the view needs all of the properties of your domain objects which is very rarely true.

Comment: An alternative would be to populate the IEnumerable object Reasons from a constructor in the MyViewModel class. Objections are of course welcome :-)